# Oracle regexp_replace - removing trailing spaces

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I am looking for some help in regards to removing trailing spaces from my queue names. The following is an example of a table that I am using:

```
QUEUE_NAME
Queue A 
Queue B
Queue C
```

The problem I have is that there is an extra space at the end of the queue name and when trying the following code:

```
SELECT
 TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM QUEUE_NAME)
FROM
 TABLE_QUEUE;
```

the space is still there.

I was reading the searches from Google and came across the following code to remove special characters [https://community.oracle.com/blogs/bbrumm/2016/12/11/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-oracle-sql] and this removed all the spaces including the one at the end. The code I wrote:

```
SELECT
     REGEXP_REPLACE(QUEUE_NAME, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', '')
    FROM
     TABLE_QUEUE;
```

Only issue I have now is that my result is shown as the following:

```
QUEUE_NAME
QueueA
QueueB
QueueC
```

I have never really used regexp_replace hence not sure what I need to change to the code to leave the spaces in between the queue names, so would really appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I could fix this.

Thanks in advance.

---- code edited as should not include `[.!?]+`

Comment: Are you sure it is space and not other whitespace character?

Comment: Hi, Lukasz, to be fair I wasn't sure, its only when i download the table data as CSV that's when I see an extra space at the end. Is there anyway for me to check?

Comment: Notepad++ and show nonvisible characters "View->Show Symbol->Show all characters"

Comment: Ok thanks will try that

Comment: Is `QUEUE_NAME` declared as being of type `CHAR`? If so, you'll need to change the data type of `QUEUE_NAME` to `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Hi Bob,`QUEUE_NAME` is defined as `VARCHAR2` already

Comment: Also when checking the results in Notepad++, there is a trailing space as when I select "Edit->Blank Operations->Trim Trailing Spaces" then the space is then removed.

Comment: For the future, it would be best to know for sure WHAT those mysterious characters were. You can find out if you run `select DUMP(queue_name) from table_queue`. Read a bit about the DUMP function and play with it, you will find it to be very helpful in many occasions.

Comment: Thanks mathguy for the tip about the `DUMP` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove space from the end of the string:

```
regexp_replace(queue_name, '[[:space:]]+$', '')
```

(The '$' in the pattern marks the end.)

If this still doesn't work, then you are dealing with some strange invisible character that is not considered space. Use

```
regexp_replace(queue_name, '[^0-9A-Za-z]+$', '')
```

instead, which, as you already know, removes all characters except for letters and digits. The '$' restricts this to the end of the string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Tried that code, still has space at the end

Comment: Okay, strange invisible character then that is not considered space. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thorsten, thanks for that, that did the trick. The '$' that I added has fixed this. Brilliant.

Comment: For future reference if I wanted to restrict this to the start and end of string, is that possible? As I tried, `REGEXP_REPLACE(QUEUE_NAME, '+^[^0-9A-Za-z]+$', '')` and that didn't work...

Comment: @MichaelOwen - the + sign only means something after a subpattern, not before it. What you do want, instead, is `regexp_replace(queue_name, '^[^0-9A-Za-z]+|[^0-9A-Za-z]+$').

Comment: mathguy, thanks for that, really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: select T653.C536870915 from T653 where 
regexp_replace(T653.C536870915, '[[:space:]]+$', '')  gets me 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action: --> What am I missing?

Comment: @Thomas: The comment section here is supposed to be for comments on the answer, not for requests. Anyway. Your regexp_replace results in a string, say 'xyz'. Your query then reads: `select T653.C536870915 from T653 where 'abc'` and the DBMS asks you: what is `where 'abc'` is supposed to mean? This is not a boolean expression resulting in true or false. You may want to compare your result to something, e.g. `where regexp_replace(T653.C536870915, '[[:space:]]+$', '') = 'soldout'`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `trim` only as in the following select statement :

```
with t(col0) as
(
 select ' Queue A  ' from dual union all
 select '   Queue B ' from dual union all
 select ' Queue C  ' from dual 
)
select trim(col0)
  from t;

trimmedText
-----------
Queue A
Queue B
Queue C
```

you get no surrounding spaces around.

Answer (score 0):

Columns of type `CHAR` (e.g. `CHAR(8)`) are always blank-padded on the right to the full width of the field. So if you store `'Queue A'` in a `CHAR(8)` field the database helpfully adds a single space to the end of it - and there's no way to remove that extra space from the column. The solution is to change the field so it's defined as either `VARCHAR2` (preferred in Oracle) or `VARCHAR`:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_QUEUE MODIFY QUEUE_NAME VARCHAR2(8);
```

Then the database will only store the characters you give it, without blank-padding the field.

Best of luck.